# Question mark gets appended to URL when error encountered?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form. When I submit and try to insert a duplicate record in the database, the page reloads and the error message is logged in the console. However, after* the page reloads, a question mark is already appended to the end of the URL. Why is that so?

Like from this:
`http://localhost/project/home`
to this (after database error occurred due to duplicate record):
`http://localhost/project/home?`

Controller:

```
public function loadBoardManagement()
{
    $role     = $this->session->userdata('role');
    $user_id  = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $board_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $role = 'Admin';
    $user_id = 1;

    if ($this->uri->segment(3) == null)
    {
        $board_id = 178;    
    }

    if ($this->session->userdata('first_board_id') !== null && $board_id == 0) 
    { 
        $board_id = $this->session->userdata('first_board_id');
    }

    $data['boards']          = $this->Board_model->getBoards($role, $user_id);
    $data['board_assignees'] = $this->Team_model->getBoardAssignees($board_id);
    $data['all_teams']       = $this->Team_model->getAllTeams();
    $data['team_quantity']   = $this->Team_model->getBoardTeamsQuantity($board_id);
    $data['board_name']      = $this->Board_model->getBoardName($board_id);
    $data['board_id']        = $board_id;

    $this->load->view('board_management', $data);
}

public function fast_signup() 
{
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $first_name = $this->input->post('first_name');
    $last_name = $this->input->post('last_name');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $role = $this->input->post('role');

    $fast_signup = $this->User_model->fastSignup($username, $password, $first_name, $last_name, $email, $role);

    if ($fast_signup)
    {
        echo 'success';
    }
    else
    {
        echo $fast_signup;
    }
}
```

**javascript:**

```
function addMember()
{
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var first_name = $('#first_name').val();
    var last_name = $('#last_name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var role = $('#role option:selected').val();
    console.log('Role: ' + role);
    console.log(username + password + first_name + last_name + email);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: base_url + 'user/fast_signup', //controller for inserting new members, but the current page is localhost/project/board/loadBoardManagement
        data: {
            'username': username,
            'password': password,
            'first_name':first_name,
            'last_name': last_name,
            'email': email,
            'role' : role
        },
        success: function(msg)
        {
            if (msg == 'success')
            {
                console.log('Member created');
                window.location.href = window.location.href;
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('Failed to create member!' + msg);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            console.log('Response: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
            console.log('Status code: ' + textStatus);
            console.log('Error thrown: ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}

$('#create_user_member').click(function() {
    addMember();
});
```

Comment: can you show the code where it redirects?

Comment: @SuthanBala which code exactly? the view, controller, or model?

Comment: The controller which does the `redirect`

Comment: @SuthanBala I updated my question

Comment: Emm... Your code show ajax communication. Page can be reloaded after OK response. You disabled default form submit action? (show HTML). You use <form action="?" ...>? This is reason. 2. Start using JSON in response: `json_encode(Array('status'=>'ok'))` and `json_encode(Array('status'=>'error','fast_signup'=>$fast_signup))`